# How to build and integrate contact form in GatsbyJS

Tags: gatsby, nodemailer

I have been trying to create a contact form using nodemailer but there is no luck, I could use netlify forms but there is a limit of 100 submissions for a free plan, therefore, I am looking for a solution which will not have any limit and I can integrate it in my site.

Comment: Can you show us what you did so far?

Comment: Currently, I don't have the code for the nodemailer integration, I am just using netlify form functions.